# Undo Manager has stopped working after binding NSTextView to NSArrayController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

When I bind `NSTextView` to `NSArrayController` in `storyBoard`, undo works correctly but `NSTextView` would loose focus each time when context is saved.
Therefore, I bound `NSTextView` to `NSArrayController` programmatically:

```
[_noteTextView bind: NSAttributedStringBinding
           toObject: _noteArrayController.selection
        withKeyPath: @"noteByUser"
            options: (@{
                        NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption : @YES,
                        NSAllowsEditingMultipleValuesSelectionBindingOption : @YES,
                        NSConditionallySetsEditableBindingOption : @YES,
                        NSRaisesForNotApplicableKeysBindingOption : @YES })];
```

Now, it do not loose focus on saving but undo functionality stopped working for `NSTextView`, other views inside `mainWindow` which are bound to `NSArrayController` in storyboard responds to undo command correctly.

Comment: Programmatical bindings should work the same as bindings in the xib. I don't think it will solve your problem. If you want to bind programatically, `selection` should be in the keypath. Is 'allows undo' switched on for the textview? Do the other views lose focus? Are changes to the text saved?

Comment: Yes, changes to textview are saved without NSTextView loosing focus, It is just the undo which do not work. When I bound NSTextView via storyboard, it started to loose focus every time I saved main context.

Comment: I checked again and, undo works but NSTextView updates it only after app is restarted. I did set NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption : @YES, why isn't it updating with undo's simultaneously.

Comment: `_noteArrayController.selection` is evaluated during execution of the bind statement. You should bind to `_noteArrayController` with keypath `selection.noteByUser`